# Prove $X_t = {W_t}^3 - 3\int^{t}_{0} W_s \, ds$ is a martingale using definition

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

> Question: Prove $X_t = {W_t}^3 - 3\int^{t}_{0} W_s \, ds$ is a martingale using definition, that is, for any $0\leq s <t, $ we have 
>   $$\mathbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s) = X_s$$
>   where $\mathcal{F}_s$ is the filtration generated by $X_s.$

I can solve the question by showing that the SDE satisfied by $X_t$ has no drift term, and thus $X_t$ is a martingale.

But I do not know how to show using definition of martingale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$X_t-X_s=(W_t-W_s+W_s)^3-W_s^3-3 \int_{s}^{t}{(W_u-W_s+W_s)du}$$

$$=\left[(W_t-W_s)^3+3(W_t-W_s)^2W_s+3(W_t-W_s)W_s^2+W_s^3\right]-W_s^3-3 \int_{s}^{t}{(W_u-W_s)du}-3W_s(t-s)$$

Taking the expectation, using the fact the independence between $W_u-W_s$ and $\mathcal{F_s}$ with $s\leq u \leq t$

$$E[(W_t-W_s)^3| \mathcal{F_s}]=E[(W_t-W_s)^3]=0$$
$$E[3(W_t-W_s)^2W_s| \mathcal{F_s}]=3W_sE[(W_t-W_s)^2]=3W_s(t-s)$$
$$E[3(W_t-W_s)W_s^2| \mathcal{F_s}]=3W_s^2E[(W_t-W_s)]=0$$
$$E\left[3 \int_{s}^{t}{(W_u-W_s)du}| \mathcal{F_s}\right]=3 \int_{s}^{t}{E\left[(W_u-W_s)| \mathcal{F_s}\right]du}=0$$

Therefore
$$E[(X_t-X_s)| \mathcal{F_s}]=3W_s(t-s)-3W_s(t-s)=0$$

or
$$E[X_t| \mathcal{F_s}]=X_s$$